# When was the first non-coinbase transaction?

Tags: blockchain, history

What's the block number? Also if it was a test transaction, then what was the first event of real commerce if know?

Comment: I don't recall the block number, but I'm pretty sure it was Satoshi sending Gavin 25 BTC. I think it was after block 70,000.

Comment: It seems Hal received the first set of BTC in block 170, but it would be interesting to find out who spent what and when during the first 100k blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [first non-coinbase transaction in the chain](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/f4184fc596403b9d638783cf57adfe4c75c605f6356fbc91338530e9831e9e16) is in [block 170](http://blockexplorer.com/b/170).  Not sure what you would consider a 'real' versus a 'test' transaction, but given that there is an entirely separate blockchain for test transactions I'd consider it as real as any other.

Comment: A transaction used for actual commerces versus a transfer of wealth to encourage use of bitcoins at a later date.

Comment: Impossible to know, unless you can track down the owners of all the early transactions and ask them.